# Using Azure Custom Vision prediction API to call a published model. but got an error CS0122

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-custom-vision

I'm very new to coding and currently trying to call a published image classification model to my C# window form.NET and using this code

https://github.com/alanazure/CustomVisionApiClassification/blob/master/CustomVisionApiClassification.Complete/PredictionConsole.cs

but got an error CS0122 'CustomVisionPredictionClient.CustomVisionPredictionClient(params DelegatingHandler[])' is inaccessible due to its protection level' error...

which I think occurred because there is an update from azure custom vision
any way to fix this?

Comment: This [particular constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices.vision.customvision.prediction.customvisionpredictionclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-cognitiveservices-vision-customvision-prediction-customvisionpredictionclient-ctor(system-net-http-delegatinghandler())) of `CustomVisionPredictionClient` is protected. that's why you are getting this error. [Check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices.vision.customvision.prediction.customvisionpredictionclient.-ctor)

Answer (score 0):

*As because custom vision prediction class library is protected is the reason for receiving error*

```
protected CustomVisionPredictionClient (params System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler[] handlers);
```

*Refer this Microsoft [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices.vision.customvision.prediction.customvisionpredictionclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet) for complete information.*